# Android: parsing JSONArray key with iterator

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a key from JSONArray which is:

```
{
    "server": [
       {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Steve",
         "email": "test@gmail.com",
         "phone": "1001001000"
       }

    ]
}
```

Since, the key, which is **id**, **name**, **email**, and **phone** can be dynamically changed, we have to parse the result without teaching the key value. That is, the system has to parse both the key and the value. So I thought getting an array and using the iterator.hasNext() will solve the problem.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString().trim());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server");
            for (int current = 0; current < jsonArray.length(); current++){
                JSONObject json_object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(current);
                Iterator iterator = json_object.keys();
                while (iterator.hasNext()){
                    hashMap.put(iterator.next().toString(), json_object.getString(iterator.next().toString()));
                }
            }
```

It doesn't work properly whether changing the iterator to **jsonObject.keys()** or **json_object.keys()**, but only parses the key value of **"id"**, and can't parse the name, email, phone.

This is how I get the JSON file:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = array();
if ($result){
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($data,
            array('id'=>$row[1],
            'name'=>$row[2],
            'email'=>$row[3],
            'phone'=>$row[4]
        ));
 }
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
$json = json_encode(array("server"=>$data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT+JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json;
```

Comment: its invalid json format check it here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I don't think it's related to PHP

Comment: @NileshRathod  it's valid json (`,` is missing only)

Comment: @AlivetoDie you mean after "id": "1" there should be ","?

Comment: yes after each one comma needed. It's just editing mistake i think

Comment: @AlivetoDie Oh, there was a comma, I just didn't enter it on a question by accident. However, an error still exists.

Comment: @Mium   you said `Since, the key, which is id, name, email, and phone can be dynamically changed`, but the code i am seeing which create json will always gave same key which are `id, name, email,phone`

Comment: @AlivetoDie that code is just an example. Since there are lots of things to be parsed, I want to integrate the code. Other activities or php(s) need version, build, or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server");
        for (int current = 0; current < jsonArray.length(); current++){
            JSONObject json_object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(current);
            Iterator iterator = json_object.keys();

            while( iterator.hasNext() ) {

                String key = (String)iterator.next();
                if ( json_object.get(key) instanceof String ) {
                    hashMap.put(key, json_object.getString(key));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("OUTPUT", Arrays.asList(hashMap).toString());
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I only get id=1, what's the problem?

Comment: @Mium didn't get you

Comment: I only get one of the outputs, not the full result.

Comment: can getting JSONObject using stringbuilder.toString() be a problem?

Comment: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference,,

Comment: Do you think this is a server problem?

Comment: @Mium i'm not sure about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179228/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-mium).

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @Mium happy to hear that Happy Coding 